# Coordinator Layout Behavior Not Working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to hide the toolbar when `Webview` is scrolled up and show when the webview is scrolled down. to achieve the behavior i found something called Coordinator Layout. But unfortunately its not working for me.
How my xml looks?

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    -------

    <AppBarLayout
       -------
        <Toolbar
           -----
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           ------
            />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <SwipeRefreshLayout
       -------------
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/globalWebView"
            ---------------------------
            ---------------------------/>
    </SwipeRefreshLayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Actually when i found its not working i tried in other way that is

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar....
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </AppBarLayout>
        <WebView...
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

But it did not worked for me. is there any solution to make it work? TIA.

Comment: Wrap your webView into `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: thanks it worked. @Wizard

Comment: How about I post an answer and you accept it? Its will help others as well.

Comment: @Wizard sure. actually it helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `webView` into `NestedScrollView` like below..

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    ....>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar....
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView
        ....
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <WebView....
            ... />
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Further, You can use `nestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)` of `NestedScrollView` as needed.